# JavaScript Code Explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I use a script called "imageLightbox" and in this Script is a line:

```
var description = $( 'a[href="' + $( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' ) + '"] img' ).attr( 'alt' );
```

Can anybody tell me what's happened there?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Variable declaration? variable assignment? string concatenation? function calls? method calls? behavior of the specific function/method WRT the arguments provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets the `alt` attribute of an `img` which is contained within an anchor with the same `href` as the `src` of `#imagelightbox`.

Broken down a bit:

```
// get the src attribute of the #imagelightbox element
var imagelightSrc = $( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' );  

// get an img contained in a anchor with an href equal to imagelightSrc
var img = $( 'a[href="' + imagelightSrc + '"] img' );

// get the alt attribute of that image
var description = img.attr( 'alt' );
```

**Useful links:**

[Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

[`attr` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `#imagelightbox` is the id of an image:

`$( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' )` returns the src (source) of an image, say "bla/foo.jpg".

The second bit of code the uses the src as part of its selector, so

```
$( 'a[href="' + $( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' ) + '"] img' )
```

effectively would become

```
$( 'a[href="bla/foo.jpg"] img' )
```

which finds an a tag with an href of `bla/foo.jpg` and gets the img element within it.

Finally the `.attr( 'alt' );` on the end, grabs the alt tag text from that element, which is returned and set in to the `description` variable.

Answer (score 0):

#### Broken into pieces

```
// get imageLightbox
var $imageLightbox =   $( '#imagelightbox' ); 

// get src of imageLightbox
var srcOfimageLightbox = $imageLightbox.attr( 'src' )

// find corresponding anchor
var $correspondingAnchor = $( 'a[href="' + srcOfimageLightbox + '"]')

// find correspponding image 
var $correspondingImage = $correspondingAnchor.find('img') 

// get alt attribute of correspponding image
var altOfcorrespondingImage = $altOfcorrespondingImage.attr( 'alt' ) 

// the description is taken from the alt attribute of the corresponding image
var description = altOfcorrespondingImage
```

Answer (score 0):

it is looking for an `img` node, which could be in all descent child nodes of an `a` node like:

```
$( 'a img' )
```

but not in any kind of `a` node, only those with a specfic `href` attribute:

```
$( 'a[href=...] img' )
```

that attribute is the value of `src` attribute of a node name with `imagelightbox` as its id:

```
var src = $( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' );
$( 'a[href="' + src + '"] img' )
```

which is probably another `img` node because of `src` node.

at the end when it finds the image it gets it `alt` attribute.

```
var src = $( '#imagelightbox' ).attr( 'src' );
var altValue = $( 'a[href="' + src + '"] img' ).attr( 'alt' );
```